# Wird Hochdeutsch relativ schnell gesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation

Momentan läuft eine [Debatte über Deutsche](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/0,1518,829484,00.html) in der Schweiz. Dabei stieß ich auf [diesen Artikel](http://www.pi-news.net/2012/04/natalie-rickli-svp-ventilklausel-fur-deutsche/) (nicht dass ich die Seite regelmäßig lesen würde :)), wo behauptet wird, "Maschinengewehr-Hochdeutsch" (ziemliche Blitzkrieg-Rhetorik, aber scheint auf der Webseite normal zu sein) sei verpönt bei den langsam sprechenden Schwaben. Dazu werden auch noch andere Behauptungen aufgestellt, beispielsweise dass Südländer dreimal so langsam sprechen wie die Norddeutschen. Ja, alles wahrscheinlich reichlich übertrieben und politisch inkorrekt. :)

Aber das bringt mich zu Frage, ob die Sprechgeschwindigkeit zwischen Schweizern, Österreichern, Deutschen, Bayern, Schwaben, … eigentlich wirklich so unterschiedlich ist, und wenn ja, womit das zusammenhängt. Wir haben da sicher alle unsere Vorurteile und Erfahrungen, drum wäre ich an einer Studie bzw. wissenschaftlichen Fakten interessiert. Sprechen Schweizer Hochschulprofessoren langsamer als deutsche, dauern die Vorlesungen doppelt so lang? ;) Man könnte ja annehmen, dass z. B. schwierigere Grammatik oder Schachtelsätze auch langsamere Sprechgeschwindigkeiten bewirken. Oder ist es einfach nur kulturell bedingt, dass die Schwaben langsamer reden, wenn sie es wirklich tun sollten.

Also noch mal ganz klar die Fragen: Gibt es diese Unterschiede objektiv gesehen, wie misst man sie (Wörter/Inhalt pro Minute), wie erklärt man sie?

Comment: Der Schweizer an sich findet gar nicht, dass er langsam spricht. Ausnahme: die Berner. Ein Berner kommt mit Beinbruch ins Krankenhaus. Der Arzt fragt, wie es dazu kam. "Ich bin auf einer Schnecke ausgerutscht." "So etwas, auf einer Schnecke! Haben Sie die nicht gesehen?" "Nein, das ging nicht." "Warum nicht?" "Sie kam so schnell von hinten."

Comment: Ich habe keinerlei Fakten, die als solche durchgehen würden. Mein Gefühl als gebürtiger Schwabe mit Freunden aus Niedersachsen, Berlin, Freiburg -- also quer durch die Republik -- behauptet, dass sich die Sprechgeschwindigkeiten nicht sonderlich unterscheiden...

Comment: Eine Erklaerung die ich von einer Schweizer Bekannten gehoert habe war, dass Schweizer es schlicht nicht gewoehnt sind Hochdeutsch zu sprechen und es beinahe soviel Konzentration erfordert wie das Sprechen einer Fremdsprache. Insofern ist ein langsamer Sprachfluss nicht wirklich ueberraschend.

Comment: @Jules Mir fällt noch Emil Steinberger ein, der schweizer Kabarettist, auch ein extremer Langsamsprecher soweit ich mich entsinne

Comment: Ich bin gebürtiger Pole. Wenn ich mit Freunden oder Familie rede, sprechen wir meistens schnell was auf polnisch, da wir scheinbar mehr Informationen in einen Satz stecken. Unsere Sätze sind viel kürzer, etc. Darüberhinaus spricht man Polnisch rel. schnell (kann man einfach an den Nachrichtensprechern im Fernsehen sehen). Mir ist aufgefallen, dass Sächsisch schnell gesprochen wird, während eigentlich alle Dialekte im Westen (auch Bayern) eher langsam.

Comment: Das halte ich fuer eine gewagte These. Ich behaupte dass man in vielen Dialekten schnell sprechen kann. Schnelles oder praegnantes sprechen ist auch eher Sprecher denn Sprachabhaengig. Ruemdrdeschaf!

Comment: @polemon Sächssch klingt nur schneller, weil wir Buchstabn einsparn... ;-)

Comment: @Hauser Ich hab den letzten Absatz mal rausgenommen. Wollte eigentlich einen Link zu der Frage auf linguistics anführen, nur leider hast du die Frage dort doch nie gestellt.

Comment: Not about German, but quite interesting. [Why does speech speed seem to vary between different languages?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/612)

Answer (score 12):

Ich bin aus Österreich (geboren in Graz, lebe seit 15 Jahren in Wien) und habe bisher noch keine regionalen Unterschiede bei der Sprechgeschwindigkeit bemerkt. Sehr wohl gibt es aber individuelle Unterschiede. Beispielsweise war der ehemalige österreichische Bundeskanzler Bruno Kreisky ein extremer Langsamsprecher. Nachrichtensprecher im Radio sprechen hingegen oft sehr schnell.

Ich glaube auch, dass sich der Ausdruck "Maschinengewehr-Hochdeutsch" wohl eher auf die stakkatoartike Artikulation als auf die Geschwindigkeit bezieht. Je weiter man im deutschen Sprachraum nach Süden kommt, desto stärker werden Vokale und Konsonanten miteinader verschliffen. Die Unterschiede zwischen t und d, p und b sowie k und g sind im Süden deutlich schwächer ausgeprägt als im Norden. Vor allem die harten Konsonanten werden im Norden viel härter ausgesprochen als im Süden.

Möglicherweise klingt dadurch ein Österreichischer Sprecher für Norddeutsche Ohren gemütlicher obwohl er nicht langsamer spricht. Und möglicherweise klingen dadurch Hanseaten für Schweizer eher steif, zugeknöpft und "gestelzt".

Comment: Neulich hab ich mal den österreichischen Club 2 gesehen und konnte da auch nicht wirklich Geschwindigkeitsunterschiede ausmachen. Dr. Pahl spricht sehr langsam, Alfred Dorfer eher schnell. Übrigens bezweifel ich, dass es Politiker gibt die noch langsamer sprechen als der Bayer Michael Glos :) Aber bayerische Politiker sind eh ein Kaliber für sich in allen Belangen...

Comment: @Hauser: **Franke**, nicht Bayer ô.o

Comment: @Jan: Sind denn Franken keine Bayern? Franken ist doch der nördliche Teil Bayerns, oder nicht? Und der angesprochene Politiker Michael Glos ist ein Politiker der CSU (Langtext: »Christlich-Soziale Union in Bayern«), also ist er ein bayrischer Politiker. Und geboren wurde er in Brünnau, das liegt im nördlichen Teil Bayerns, zwischen Würzburg und Bamberg, also in Bayern, somit ist er auch ein gebürtiger Bayer. Dass er auch gebürtiger Franke (und gebürtiger Deutscher und gebürtiger Europäer) ist, bestreitet niemand. Aber bei deiner Aussage "nicht Bayer" sehe ich Erklärungsbedarf.

Comment: Eine alte, tief sitzende Rivalität der bayerischen (oder vielleicht nur: »bairischen«?) und fränkischen Teile des politischen Bayerns. In Altbayern hört man gerne »Bayern und Franken« (wobei dann die Schwaben sich gerne auf den Schlips getreten fühlen). Im Übrigen wird vor Allem in Nürnberg sehr gerne darauf hingewiesen, dass man (stolzer) Franke und eben nicht Bayer sei.

Comment: @Jan: sprachlich findet sich die Rivalität zwischen bairisch und fränkisch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte . Folglich gibt einen Unterschied zwischen Bayern (Einwohner des Gebiets) und Baiern (Sprecher des Dialekts).

Answer (score 5):

Man kann eigentlich nicht sagen, dass es im Allgemeinen regionale Unterschiede gibt. Ich kenne (der Arbeit wegen) Menschen aus ganz Deutschland sowie aus Österreich und der Schweiz und kann nicht sagen, dass man allgemein sagen kann, dass manche schneller sprechen als andere.

Trotzdem habe ich festgestellt, dass es wesentlich wahrscheinlicher ist, im Norden einen Schnellsprecher zu finden als im Süden. Ein Beispiel: Ich habe in einer Arbeitsgruppe zwei Hamburger, drei Sachsen, zwei Schwaben und mehrere Berliner/Brandenburger. Während ich noch *nie* gehört habe, dass die beiden Schwaben schnell reden (selbst wenn wir Fußball spielen und das Spiel hektisch wird, bleiben beide sehr entspannt), die beiden Hamburger jedoch öfters eine flinkere Sprachweise verwenden (auch in normalen Gesprächen).
Die drei Sachsen hingegen machen es eher gemischt: Im Allgemeinen sprechen sie eher gemütlich, teilweise springen sie in Nebensätzen aber kurz extrem mit dem Tempo, um danach wieder normal weiterzureden.

Trotz dieses Beispiels denke ich nicht, dass es regionale Unterschiede gibt, denn: Die Schwaben kommen vom Land; und genau da liegt es für mich: Während die Brandenburger auch eher in einem moderaten Tempo sprechen (trotz allem aber schnell sprechen *können*), sind die Berliner, die geographisch nicht sehr weit entfernt sind, viel hektischer, was die Sprachweise angeht.
Genau so lässt sich meiner Meinung nach das Bild zeichnen: je ruhiger die Umgebung, desto ruhiger die Sprechweise.
Trotzdem kommt natürlich (wie von Hubert Schölnast bereits genannt) die Sprechweise (bezogen auf Dialekt/Mundart/Ähnliches) allgemein eher zum Tragen als die Schnelligkeit beim Sprechen.